# How to initialize Cropme

Tags: jquery

How can I properly initialize Cropme
**I can not see zoom sliders and rotate sliders**

[image]
My code is:

```
var element = $('.example').cropme();

new Vue({

  "rotation": {
    "slider": true,
    "enable": true,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "transformOrigin": "viewport"

});
```

https://shpontex.github.io/cropme/

Comment: What makes you think you've included both jQuery and the cropme library properly, and placed it properly on the webserver, so it can be loaded by your web page and javascript code?  Where's the CSS? You need to show the code, and even then there are questions about your website configuration... are the directories readable? Are the paths what you think they are? Be sure to get into the developer mode of your browser and look at the known resources and check around to be sure it's finding everything where you think it is. Make sure the code that's supposed to load the library is executed.

Comment: Technically cropme usage specifics are out of the scope of StackOverflow because you're not asking for programing fixes pers say, asking for help with how to use offsite libraries, and besides whatever coding errors you  may have made there may be versioning issues, problems in the library you're using, knowledge of the library people don't have (There's no tag for cropme on StackOverflow, is there? Meaning it's probably too specialized to expect there to be knowledge here about it).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery selector, use plain JavaScript `document.querySelector`.
Then, create a new instance of Cropme selecting the element.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.example');
var cropme = new Cropme(element);
```

Finally, you can set an image to it.

```
cropme.bind({
    url: 'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/09a3d5_55fd1b81f9094845ae7e43ec23c869b6~mv2_d_3072_2048_s_2.jpg'
});
```